# Tenses and Verbs

Tags: verbs, tenses

What kind of verbs are -- is, are, were ?
How do these words effect the tense of a sentence?

What tense is the sentence " They are engaged in something...." ?

1) They engage in doing something.
2) They are engaged in doing something.

With respect to above two sentences,

-- when is one used over the other.
-- what tense is sentence 1, what tense is sentence 2?

Answer (score 2):

They're [auxiliary verbs](http://encyclopedia.farlex.com/Auxilliary+verb), *used with a ‘main’ verb to help form a specific tense, and also negatives and questions. Meaning a ‘helping’ verb, the auxiliary verbs are to **be**, to **have**, and to **do**, as in **‘That can be changed’, ‘You must have known’,** and **‘You do see’.***

OP's examples are both **present tense**. The "main" verb is *"to engage [in]"* - followed by the present participle *doing [something]*.

But in the second sentence, *"to be"* (as present tense *"are"*) is the auxiliary verb forming "present continuous" tense. The main verb, relieved of any requirement to carry tense, adopts an almost "adjectival" role describing a "state of being" (as in, say, *"They are annoyed"*), where we naturally use the past participle.